# How can I use Jersey libraries to convert a JSON string to something more parseable in Java?

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I am new to REST and am trying to mess around with it a bit to get accustomed to it. I have decided to create a little project that involves accessing location data from Google's API.

There are a lot of posts about converting JSON strings to objects in Java but most of them seem to use different libraries than what I'm using, which is Jersey. Right now, I'm using the Google Maps API to successfully return information about a location given by the user, but right now, it just returns a string like so:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "San Antonio",
               "short_name" : "San Antonio",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bexar County",
               "short_name" : "Bexar County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Texas",
               "short_name" : "TX",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "San Antonio, TX, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 29.73872,
                  "lng" : -98.22295799999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 29.2241411,
                  "lng" : -98.8058509
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 29.4241219,
               "lng" : -98.49362819999999
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 29.73872,
                  "lng" : -98.22295799999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 29.2241411,
                  "lng" : -98.8058509
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJrw7QBK9YXIYRvBagEDvhVgg",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I need to have some way to easily parse this kind of information, and I know Java has hash tables built in. Is there any easy way to convert this information? Possibly into a hash table of some sort? Please also include the usage of whatever object you convert it to, so I can see the exact way I would need to parse it to get the information. Here is the relevant part of the code I have written so far.

```
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    WebTarget target = client.target("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + loc + "&sensor=false");

    String result = target.request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class);
```

Thanks to anyone who can help out :)

Comment: What do you mean by easily parse? And in what format do you want the information to be in, HashTable or what? These couple of things are not clear from your question and code.

Comment: Read this: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Comment: You can easily use jackson with jersey. Just build corresponding plain old java objects.

Comment: By easily parse, I mean that I want to be able to access the data quickly and easily. For example, if I want to display the formatted address, I could do something like "results[formatted_address]" or if I wanted the lat from northeast bound, I would do "results[geometry][bounds][northeast][lat]".

As I said, a hash table is one option, but I'm just looking for anything that will allow me to access the information as easily as I've explained. If you think a hash table is the way, then that's the one.

Comment: @petul I'm not sure what you mean by "build corresponding plain old java objects". Can you please type out a full answer and explain what you mean?

Comment: @PritamBanerjee can you also write out a more full answer explaining what you are saying?

Answer (score 1):

> There are a lot of posts about converting JSON strings to objects in Java but most of them seem to use different libraries than what I'm using, which is Jersey.

Based on this, I am assuming you try to convert the JSON in Java Objects. If you want to go ahead and store some of the member variables in HashMaps, you can do that if you want to.

So first of all, you need the following dependencies for your project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

The error in your current code is that you expect JSON, not text/plain. Also you do not want a String object, you want a corresponding POJO. This might look like this:

```
String loc = "New York";
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.register(MapperProvider.class);
WebTarget target = client.target("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + URLEncoder.encode(loc, "UTF-8") + "&sensor=false");
GoogleMapsResponse result = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(GoogleMapsResponse.class);
```

The MapperProvider is required to enforce a naming strategy, mainly the JSON's snake_case to Java's camelCase, and looks like this:

```
@Provider
public class MapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public MapperProvider() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(
                PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
    }


    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> aClass) {
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

The start of the GoogleMaps Class is

```
public class GoogleMapsResponse {
    public Result[] results;
    public String status;
}
```

Result has to contain an AddressComponent array, where the AddressComponent class contains String longName, String shortName a Type array etc.

This will be up to you to model and implement